# Random reboots in and out of primarily gaming sessions 

Tags: windows-7, reboot

Edit: This happens consistently in games but also occasionally (once every 4 or 5 days) when having trivial apps like Skype open.

So I built a slightly new PC back in May. The upgrade consisted of a new CPU (i5-2500k), a new miniatx case, a motherboard (p8p67-m), some ram and a PSU (an OCZ 600W). The other stuff such as the 5850 I put into this one as I had absolutely no problems with it along with the hard drives.

However, as soon as I started playing a game from 10 minutes to 2 hours, I would get an abrupt restart. No minidump created/found as far as I can see, automatic restart disabled...just a complete hard reboot. This happens within the 10min - 2hr range in a game but without a game, it does happen to only maybe once ever 4-5 days. For example, I was just on skype the other day and for no reason it did the same hard reboot.

I have done memtest86+ up to around 93% (?) with no signs of error. I then messed around with drivers and did a new install of windows 7 with no help. I've tried different games with the same behavior. I switched out the PSU finally with a new Corsair 700W and still, the same issue. I also changed the case to a different thermaltake mini-atx one.

Thinking that maybe the microatx case (overheating) was a problem, I logged the temps before a complete reboot and here they are, I don't think they look that crazy:

**CPU**

RealTemp:

- Date : 9/11/11
- Time: 23:42:00
- C0(F): 138
- C1(F): 136
- C2(F): 133
- C3(F): 136

**GPU**

- Date:      2011-09-11 23:42:23
- GPU Core Clock [MHz]: 725.0
- GPU Memory Clock [MHz]: 1000.0
- GPU Temperature [°C]: 79.0
- Fan Speed (%) [%]: 33
- Fan Speed (RPM) [RPM]: 2324
- GPU Load [%]: 87
- GPU Temp. #1 [°C]:  80.0
- GPU Temp. #2 [°C]:  83.0
- GPU Temp. #3 [°C]: 82.5
- Memory Usage (Dedicated) [MB]: 276
- Memory Usage (Dynamic) [MB]:40
- VDDC [V]:1.0875
- VDDC Current [A]:34.8
- VDDC Phase #1 Temperature [°C]: 68
- VDDC Phase #2 Temperature [°C]: 68
- VDDC Phase #3 Temperature [°C]: 67

So to sum it up, hard reboots, no minidump that I can see, kernel-power error only in event log, the older 5850 worked fine in my old build and this happened very quickly once I switched over to the new hardware. Meaning, it wasn't like it was a gradual thing which occurred after two weeks stable but rather right away. I only bring it up now since I've gotten to the point of frustration with this.

Comment: This is most probably a hardware failure probably temperature-related, since it happens more on games. This is hard to diagnose specially when you don't know when it would happen. I would try replacing hardware components, starting with the power supply. On most similar scenarios I've seen, it's usually either a mobo or a power supply hardware problem (poor components).

Comment: Yea but I already replaced the PSU once and this time with a corsair I mean, it would really be amazing if both were shoddy.

Comment: Check the bios for a temp log.

Comment: 83° on the GPU doesn't sound nice. (180°F). Coupled to the fact that it only happens when you play games...

Comment: This may sound completely dumb but when GPU overheats, shouldn't I see some weird artifacting occurring? Not a complete restart?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: One of the two sticks of ram was causing the issue.